# how to add new iptables rule based on current rule

Tags: iptables

I haven't really played around at all with iptables so I am quite clueless here. This MySQL server I'm currently working on rejects all connections except for whitelisted sources. I need to add a new IP but not sure how to duplicate the current rule

`iptable -L` lists this rule that i need to duplicate:

`ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.65.0.1           anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql`

How would I go about adding a new rule in for a different IP address?

edit: I guess I should add that I've been looking at different examples and instructions but before I try anything I just wanted to post the question here to see if anybody can provide the exact command to add the rule.

Answer (score 0):

just for the record here's the answer:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $IP_ADDRESS -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`